# How to find reverse percentage increase in javascript

Tags: math

I have two variable as below

```
var Price = 100;
var DiscountRate = 3;
```

I calculate percentage of **Price** variable

After the calculation process, the result looks like below

```
97
```

I want to reach 100 when I increase 3% from 97 afterwards.But when i increase the number 97 by 3%, i get a figure of 99

How can i do this by using javascript ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you get the 3% from 97. It should be the 3% of 100 so 3 + 97 = 100.

Comment: I really think this question was marked as a duplicate too soon… but it does  sounds like a math problem more than a javascript problem?

Comment: Increase of 3% on top of 97 is 99.91, so while display decimal are truncated or you have removed them. 
Formula to get 100 is  (y*100)/(100-x)
Y is the current value and x is the discount

(97*100)/(100-3) = 100

Comment: @Dencio because  Price is 97 in database so if i increase %3 it should give me 100

Comment: @ArihantJain what about %15 from 100 ? Value is 85 if you increase %15 it displays 97,75 how can i find 100 now ?

Comment: put same values in formula
(85*100)/(100-15) = 8500/85 = 100

Comment: @SonerSevinc its a math question and formula is correct.

Comment: @ArihantJain if you answer i will accept best answer thanks my friend

Comment: @SonerSevinc the formula should be price = 100 / (100 - discount) * discountedPrice.